# Download files that aren't in the web page where they are posted

Tags: curl, wget

I'm trying to download all files from this web page : https://www.lezioni4all.com/ase/appunti
So I'm using "wget" command, it didn't work so I did some researches and I found that on the web page above (when I click on the resource that I want to visualise) it opens the document in a new web page and the path is something like : http//something/resource/%10hi%10Ineedof%10thisresource

(If you open the link above and choose one of the elements in the page, for example "conflitti", you will see that there is a kind of "preview" of the item and then when you click on the bottom row the resource will be opened on a new window with the same title that you visualise on the main page but with some percentage like %10,%20... in the name).

Do you know how I could download files that can't be downloaded just putting the url of the page where they are posted?

I already tried these commands :

```
wget --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p -E -e robots=off --no-parent -P ~/Desktop/ASE_lezioni4all https://www.lezioni4all.com/ase/appunti

wget --page-requisites -p --convert-links  -P ~/Desktop/ASE_lezioni4all https://www.lezioni4all.com/ase/appunti
```

And other, I receive only blank files that open a white window on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF URLs are embedded in javascript `onclick` attributes.  You can `grep` those:

```
wget -qO- https://www.lezioni4all.com/ase/appunti | 
  grep -o "https://www\.lezioni4all\.com/files/[^']*\.pdf"
```

You can download them using the no-clobber option `-nc` (since every document is linked twice) and `-i`:

```
wget -nc -P ~/Desktop/ASE_lezioni4all -i <(
  wget -qO- https://www.lezioni4all.com/ase/appunti |
  grep -o "https://www\.lezioni4all\.com/files/[^']*\.pdf")
```

Comment: Very good work! I didn't know it was an onclick property, thanks!

Comment: I was changing some lines of code, I have a question for you : I didn't see the path to "files" in the web page. Which is its meaning and why you used it? ( I mean in this line : grep -o "https://www\.lezioni4all\.com/files/[^']*\.pdf"). )

Comment: The onclick attribute looks like this `onclick="flightbox('https://www.lezioni4all.com/files/ASE/Appunti/Appunti%20Teoria.pdf?...'` and a shorter regex like `https://[^']*\.pdf` seems to work as well. But since all download files are somewhere under `https://www.lezioni4all.com/files/` I used that as base for the regex.

Comment: But will this work for most of the sites ? I mean to write http...com/files to find the right page with all documents inside?